# moving a row of a pandas dataframe but index unchanged

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

d = np.random.rand(10,3)
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df

          0         1         2
0  0.740335  0.957937  0.611504
1  0.164772  0.469355  0.310799
2  0.666506  0.030054  0.986393
3  0.191827  0.554556  0.707453
4  0.278617  0.532423  0.095124
5  0.659526  0.413681  0.588372
6  0.285892  0.466231  0.268647
7  0.559664  0.274913  0.618610
8  0.572839  0.490969  0.194019
9  0.028767  0.332626  0.290148

# move the third row to top
df.iloc[:3] = df.iloc[[2,0,1]]
df
          0         1         2
0  0.666506  0.030054  0.986393
1  0.740335  0.957937  0.611504
2  0.164772  0.469355  0.310799
3  0.191827  0.554556  0.707453
4  0.278617  0.532423  0.095124
5  0.659526  0.413681  0.588372
6  0.285892  0.466231  0.268647
7  0.559664  0.274913  0.618610
8  0.572839  0.490969  0.194019
9  0.028767  0.332626  0.290148
```

The index is unchanged.

I tried
`df.index[:3] = df.index[[2,0,1]]` (raise error) or `df.index.values[:3] = df.index.values[[2,0,1]]`, there is no error raised but the index is still unchanged.

Comment: thanks for the comments. I edited with sample codes.

Comment: Are you expecting the index of the first 3 rows to also be 2,0,1 in this case?

Comment: Yes, I expect the index moves with the values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the index to also reflect the updated row, you need to use [df.reindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html)

```py
In [25]: np.random.seed(5)
    ...: d = np.random.rand(5, 3)
    ...: df = pd.DataFrame(d)
    ...: df
Out[25]:
          0         1         2
0  0.221993  0.870732  0.206719
1  0.918611  0.488411  0.611744
2  0.765908  0.518418  0.296801
3  0.187721  0.080741  0.738440
4  0.441309  0.158310  0.879937

In [26]: df.reindex([2,0,1,*df.index[3:]])
Out[26]:
          0         1         2
2  0.765908  0.518418  0.296801
0  0.221993  0.870732  0.206719
1  0.918611  0.488411  0.611744
3  0.187721  0.080741  0.738440
4  0.441309  0.158310  0.879937
```

Answer (score 1):

`iloc` will try to align the index.

For this reason, when the values are assigned back they will go right back to their initial location. Index 0 will align to index 0, index 1 will align to index 1, etc...

```
df.iloc[[2, 0, 1]]
```

```
          0         1         2
2  0.765908  0.518418  0.296801
0  0.221993  0.870732  0.206719
1  0.918611  0.488411  0.611744
```

(Note the index values)

---

To preserve the index values join the two DataFrame pieces together [`append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html#pandas-dataframe-append) or [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(5)
d = np.random.rand(5, 3)
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df = df.iloc[[2, 0, 1]].append(df.iloc[3:])
```

OR

```
df = pd.concat((df.iloc[[2, 0, 1]], df.iloc[3:]))
```

`df` Before:

```
          0         1         2
0  0.221993  0.870732  0.206719
1  0.918611  0.488411  0.611744
2  0.765908  0.518418  0.296801
3  0.187721  0.080741  0.738440
4  0.441309  0.158310  0.879937
```

`df` after:

```
          0         1         2
2  0.765908  0.518418  0.296801
0  0.221993  0.870732  0.206719
1  0.918611  0.488411  0.611744
3  0.187721  0.080741  0.738440
4  0.441309  0.158310  0.879937
```

---

(To match shown expected output)

To move without the indexes use [`values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html#pandas-dataframe-values) or [`to_numpy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html) to prevent the aligning behaviour:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(5)
d = np.random.rand(5, 3)
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df.iloc[:3] = df.iloc[[2, 0, 1]].values

print(df)
```

`df` After:

```
          0         1         2
0  0.765908  0.518418  0.296801
1  0.221993  0.870732  0.206719
2  0.918611  0.488411  0.611744
3  0.187721  0.080741  0.738440
4  0.441309  0.158310  0.879937
```

Comment: How about the index? The index doesn't move with the row. and manually set `df.index.values[:3] = df.index.values[[2,0,1]]` doesn't work

Comment: You'll either need to join the pieces as I've noted in my edit, or create a new index based on the other answer. See the edits. @ddzzbbwwmm

Comment: For me, it's strange `df.iloc[[2,0,1]]` returns a dataframe with index also moved (as shown in your post), but the assignment only changes the values, not the index.

Comment: That's the point. iloc aligns indexes together. There are a __ton__ of pandas operations where you __want__ the order of your dataframe not to change when adding a new column (for example). You are specifically trying to get around one of the core data integrity features of pandas DataFrames.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
np.random.seed(42)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,3))
```

[image]

```
df = df.iloc[[2,0,1]].append(df.iloc[3:])
```

[image]

Comment: you would like to arrange the first 3 rows and append the rest?